# Understanding query.fromVertices api in Arangodb graph module

Tags: graph, arangodb, multi-model-database

https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/082a78596fcb2241508f02881e3acb5834eb20da/Documentation/Books/Manual/Graphs/GeneralGraphs/FluentAQLInterface.mdpp#L573-L581

If you look at the above link, the definition of `fromVertices` says that it should select all vertices from where an edge( that was selected in the previous step) originated.

In the example discussed, The  `"married"` edge in this case returns Alice and Charlie which is OK.
Following which if you write `query.fromVertices({name:"Alice})` you get Alice vertex which is also OK

**Question**

But now if you write `query.fromVertices([{name:'Alice'},{name:'Charly'}])` why would you get 8 vertices as shown in the execution result.
Shouldn't it only return Alice and Charly vertices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Got the clarification on this https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1531

Seems like an issue.